What does TRMSN mean in takeoff obstacle notes?
In the takeoff obstacle notes for KMDT Rwy 31, it lists a Trmsn tower. What does Trmsn mean?

Are you referring to this?

Link
I think that is pretty clearly a "Transmission Tower", like a radio-antenna obstacle to be avoided.

So, "transmission tower" is too long and gets abbreviated, but "power transmission line" is spelled out?

The transmission tower is specified as 1.5NM away, but the Power line is 1194 feet away.
Mixing and converting non-associated units!  I have no idea what the conversion factor between feet and nautical miles is!

I'm sure this is right too, but a source of abbreviations is usually available in aviation to be definitive.

@abelenky: 1 NM is 6076.12 feet.
